# String function on filenames and adding as additional column

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have CSV files in blob storage with underscore delimited filenames such as `100001_1036_1595841882.csv`. I want to push these CSVs into Azure Synapse but with columns added for each delimited field in the file name.

I've tried using the new "Additional columns" feature in the Copy activity, but somehow I can't use string functions with `$$FILEPATH` (see the image below). It's fine with just `$$FILEPATH` alone.

[image]

Comment: You could push the filename into Synapse and then use `STRING_SPLIT` to split them later, using a Stored Proc task in  ADF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the copy activity but you have to take a different approach then using the $$FILEPATH variable which is not possible to manipulate using the "Add dynamic content' formula builder.

If you instead were to pass in the file name as a parameter to the pipeline you can manipulate it as you normally do. E.g if you have an event based trigger you can pull the filename from there.

[image]

In the screenshot above you can see how I pulled out the different part of the filename using the `@split(pipeline().parameters.fileName, '_')[0]` function. I do that for each part and also add the `$$FILEPATH` to get the full filename (you could of course use the value from `@pipeline().parameters.fileName` instead). For the last part I also removed the file extension.

When you do the mapping between source and sink the additional columns will show up as any column in the source dataset.

Once the pipeline execution complete the SQL table contains all relevant data

[image: Screenshot of data once written to sink DB]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't follow this answer exactly, but it really helped me understand a few things.

Comment: Great! Would you consider accepting the answer as is or do you think something is missing to better answer you question?