# How to extract filename from $$FILEPATH in Synapse copy activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

[image]

$$FILEPATH here gives me values like 'folder/sub/sub1/filename.ext'
I want to consistently extract filename.ext only. Can I do that in the copy activity itself?

I currently do it with a stored procedure afterwards but that's a slow update.

```
update [table-x]
set Filename = right(Filename, charindex('/', reverse(Filename) + '/') - 1)
where Filename like '%/%'
```

Screenshots in [here|https://stackoverflow.com/a/63170857/300248] by @mjonsing suggest it may be possible, but I don't know exactly how to.

Comment: What has @mjonsing done is add a parameter which's value is 'folder/sub/sub1/filename.ext'. Then use the expression to get 'filename.ext'.

Comment: @SteveZhao that solution requires passing the filename as parameter to the copy activity, otherwise it seems impossible to refer to the $$FILEPATH or related filename additional column

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve the original filenames and paths in the target location, you can do that in 'Copy Data' activity itself.

Either choose 'Preserve Hierarchy' or None in Copy behavior (in Copy data activity /Sink setting). If you choose 'Flatten hierarchy', file name and path won't be preserved.

[image]